# How do I use canvas to draw this background shape?

Tags: image, html, canvas, background

In a design that I'm working on, there is a recurring image background shape that appears several times in different sizes throughout the site. For example, one page uses it as a huge background images, where the top and bottom part of this image is cut off by the browser edges.

It's not an easy pattern to create with canvas, but as far as I know it's possible. Here's what it looks like.

[image]

Am I better off making several images of this same pattern or is this background image easy to recreate through canvas? If it is appropriate for canvas, how do I go about recreating it in the various sizes? I wish I knew how to begin something like this using canvas but it's above my skillset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've converted your shape to an SVG shape here: https://gist.github.com/1321653 — use it as you'd like.

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg), SVG is supported on all common browsers except for IE8 and earlier.

For IE8 and earlier you might be able to combine [canvg](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/), a SVG-to-canvas library, with [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/), a canvas emulator for IE8 and earlier. Or you could display a rectangle with a background color — IE users might not miss the splat.

*Edit*: You could also get creative with CSS3 background gradients, ala http://www.ecsspert.com/ (famous logos created with only CSS), but compatibility is low across browsers.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think about this? Thank you! I know there are svg files, but how do i take this code and convert it into a file? i don't know enough about svg files to do this myself.

Comment: Check out the "Resources:" headers on http://caniuse.com/svg — you could even embed it into a `<script>` tag like [this](http://codinginparadise.org/projects/svgweb/samples/javascript-samples/svg_inline.html?svg.render.forceflash=false).

Comment: Okay great, I'll look up the different resources and hopefully figure out how to convert your code into an SVG file. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I should ask one other thing. If this same graphic was marked up with canvas, would the size of the code be more or less than the svg? I'm trying to do this inline rather than embeded to save on rendering/load time and amount of requests the site goes through using HTML5.

Comment: Oh wow, I see that manipulating the size and color of this is not easy or straight forward. I'm not sure this is gonna work. Oh, and I did see the CSS3 backgrounds link just earlier today. It looks really good but without tons of hours of trial and error, I have no idea how I'd quickly come up with code for this! Is there something I'm missing that allows people to easily code SVG, Canvas or CSS3 BG images like in that link? Or is everyone just much faster than me at coding this type of stuff? haha

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can change colors — see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481641/change-svg-colour) and [this library](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). I think you can manipulate SVG elements kind of like DOM objects. You can embed the SVG in the HTML, thus the resulting page size should be the sum of SVG and HTML. :)